# How to create a view that returns a 2x2 (or NxN) matrix of results

Tags: sqlite

So I know enough SQL just to be really dangerous (I don't normally work the back-end) but cannot get the following view to be created successfully ;) The result set I'm after is a data set that has rows assigned as a column alias from multiple tables (instead of a 1xN flat of all columns). There is a many-to-one relationship when looking at the main table, based on foreign keys associated to the row id of the appropriate related table.

Ideally I'd like a data set that looks like this in the return:

```
dataset.transaction_row[n]: col1, col2, col3, coln... (columns from the transaction table)
dataset.category_row[n]: col1, co2, col3, coln... (columns from the category table)
```

and so on...

I get the following error:

```
Query Error: near "AS": syntax error Unable to execute statement
```

From:

```
CREATE VIEW view_unreconciled_transactions 
AS SELECT account_transaction.* AS transaction_row, 
          category.* AS category_row,
          memorized.name_rule_replace OR account_transaction.name AS payee   
FROM account_transaction
LEFT JOIN memorized ON account_transaction.memorized_key = memorized.id
LEFT JOIN category ON account_transaction.category_key = category.id
WHERE status != 2
ORDER BY account_transaction.dt_posted DESC
```

It seems easy enough since the result-column selector is repeatable which includes expressions (referencing sqlite's syntax diagrams). In reference to the error, I'm assuming it's complaining about the 2nd 'AS' where I'm trying to get table.* assigned as an alias. Any help in the right direction is appreciated. If I had to, I suppose I could explicitly state all columns but that feels like a kludge.

Answer (score 1):

The `AS` modifier can only be applied to a single column, not to a collection such as the * you used.  You will have to break them out into specific names, (which is best practice IMHO anyway)

It looks like you want to make a "pivot table".  They can be tricky to make in a database. I can say that if you a data result, where each row comes from a different table source, and the columns form each table are IDENTICAL, then you could try using a `UNION` statement to join the different results together like they are just one dataset.

NOTE that the columns all take their naming cue from the first dataset in a UNION and the datatype all need to be the same.

Comment: Thanks for the response. For this view, there are several FK's of "metadata" that would belong to the particular row in question, and my initial naive thinking was I would be able to sweep this into a single select. I'm used to big enough projects where a middle-tier is used, I guess I've been spoiled from that team doing all the work ;) I haven't gotten to this part of my project yet, but I'm thinking this will end up being a sequenced query like the rest of what I do.